# Android app doesn't show layout everytime

Tags: android, xamarin

My test Android app is not showing the Layout every time,

The app loads fine on device and emulator but it waits there and exits out after some time and sometimes it loads controls (Button ,EditText etc)  fine .

i cant figure out what is wrong.

here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="@+id/textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="username" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And Activity Code :

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Telephony;
using AndroidApplication2.TestWebServiceName;

namespace AndroidApplication2
{
    [Activity(Label = "Test App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);


            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            EditText EditView = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.textPersonName);
            EditView.Text = ((TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService)).ToString(); // WebService();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem your are accessing TelephonyManager without a proper permission being set in your AndroidManifest.xml. E.g. READ_PHONE_STATE as well as other.

-- OR --

try to remove the following line of code,

```
EditView.Text = ((TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService)).ToString(); // WebService();
```